# Uniform vs Non-uniform Attackers

Tags: provable-security, security-definition, random-oracle-model

There is a concept of attackers gaining some information before attacking a system and those attackers being called ***non-uniform attackers***. How do the security proofs for cryptographic primitives in the case of *uniform attackers* and *non-uniform attackers* differ?

This question is in reference to [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/937.pdf) paper.